# SQL - Splitting a column based on the values

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to split a column from a result set into 2 columns based on the values from the column.
So a user can subscribe to multiple items and the user can have 2 email addresses which can receive this subscription.
The result set gives a list of subscriptions and their corresponding entries for subscribed email ids.

DB details

```
Table 1 - user_subscriptions

user_id 
email_id - 1 for email id 1 and 2 for email id 2
subscription_id

Table 2 - subscriptions 

subscription_id
subscription_name
```

Now I need all the subscriptions for the user whether subscribed by either of the email ids or not.
So I get a result set something like this

```
+----------------------+----------+
| subscription_name    | email_id |
+----------------------+----------+
| item1                | 1        |
| item1                | 2        |
| item2                | null     |
| item3                | 1        |
| item4                | null     |
| item5                | 2        |
+----------------------+----------+
```

So I'm looking to split the above result set into something like below

```
+-------------------+---------+---------+
| subscription_name | email_1 | email_2 |

+-------------------+---------+---------+
| item1             | 1 or Y  | 1 or Y  |
| item2             | 0 or N  | 0       |
| item3             | 1       | 0       |
| item4             | 0       | 0       |
| item5             | 0       | 1       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

Hope this question makes sense. Any help would be appreciated!

Updated -----------

Sample Data:

`subscriptions -
+-----------------+-------------------+
| subscription_id | subscription_name |
+-----------------+-------------------+
|               1 | item1             |
|               2 | item2             |
|               3 | item3             |
|               4 | item4             |
|               5 | item5             |
+-----------------+-------------------+`

user_subscriptions

`+---------+----------+-----------------+
| user_id | email_id | subscription_id |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
|     101 |        1 |               1 |
|     101 |        2 |               1 |
|     101 |        1 |               3 |
|     101 |        2 |               5 |
|     102 |        1 |               1 |
|     102 |        2 |               1 |
+---------+----------+-----------------+`

Expected Result:

For user_id = 101

`+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| subscription_id | subscription_name | mail_1 | mail_2 |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|               1 | item1             | Y      | Y      |
|               2 | item2             | N      | N      |
|               3 | item3             | Y      | N      |
|               4 | item4             | N      | N      |
|               5 | item5             | N      | Y      |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+`

Comment: What does mean `1 or Y` and `0 or N` in your desired output?

Comment: The result if subscribed would be either 1 or Y. It's just the format I want the output in. For now it could be 1 if subscribed or 0 if not.

Comment: As per my answer below - I'd check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114446/817132 - which might give you a cleaner answer for sybase specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     S.subscription_id, 
     S.subscription_name,
     CASE 
         WHEN US1.mail_ID IS NULL THEN 'N'
         ELSE 'Y'
     END mail_1,
     CASE 
         WHEN US2.mail_ID IS NULL THEN 'N'
         ELSE 'Y'
     END mail_2
FROM subscriptions S
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions US1
  ON S.subscription_id = US1.subscription_id
 AND US1.mail_id = 1
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions US2
  ON S.subscription_id = US2.subscription_id
 AND US2.mail_id = 2
WHERE us1.user_id = 5 -- or use a variable @user_ID
  OR  us2.user_id = 5
```

Comment: Hi Juan, both the tables aren't linked by the user_id. They are linked using subscription_id.

Comment: sorry, i will fix it now

Comment: :) I'm close to what I want from this solution Juan but i'm trying to get the subscriptions only for a user_id. Help?

Comment: I include a `where` for you

Comment: With the `where` only the items that are subscribed to will be available. I've edited my original questions with sample data.

Comment: Added us1.user_id = 5 in the join condition. I've got it working now. Super thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional aggregate:

```
select us.subscription_name,
     -- there's at least one email
   CASE WHEN MIN(us.email_id) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as email_1,
     -- there's more than one email
   CASE WHEN MIN(us.email_id) <> MAX(us.email_id) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as email_2
from subscriptions as s
left join user_subscriptions as us
on s.subscription_id = us.subscription_id
where us.user_id = ...  
group by us.subscription_name
```

Comment: Hello there, Check item5 case, I think your query will show `1 - 0` instead of OP sample `0 - 1`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: If those `id`s are actually `0` and `1` it's easy to rewrite using `MIN=1` and `MAX=2`. The OP needs to add more details about the actual data...

Comment: @dnoeth - The values can be 1 or 0. I can handle that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked in sybase before, but I'm fairly sure the following SQL will translate easily (or even run directly):

```
SELECT
    s.subscription_name,
    COUNT(email_1.subscription_id) AS email_1,
    COUNT(email_2.subscription_id) AS email_2
FROM subscriptions AS s
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions AS email_1 ON (
    s.subscription_id = email_1.subscription_id AND
    email_1.email_id = 1
)
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions AS email_2 ON (
    s.subscription_id = email_2.subscription_id AND
    email_2.email_id = 2
)
;
```

You could also say `IF(email_1.subscription_id IS NOT NULL, 'Y', 'N')` etc in the `SELECT` to return a straight-forward yes/no rather than a count etc.

It works on the principle that the list of `LEFT JOIN` statements will match any "user subscription" record with `email_id=1` and `email_id=2` etc.

**My lack of sybase knowledge disclaimer:** ANSI SQL is can't perform `PIVOT` - if sybase does, you could do this far more elegantly I'm sure.  There's another question+answer which hints that sybase can do such things; it'd be worth your while looking there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114446/817132

Hope it helps!